# How to stop MSBuild copy tasks from automatically retrying

Tags: visual-studio-2012

If output binaries were locked in Visual Studio 2010 (or older), the build would simply fail and say it could not copy because the files were in use.

Now it goes into a retry loop, which is really annoying because:

- It can't be interrupted
- It doesn't help the situation

It just means I have to wait longer for the build to fail.

Does anyone know how to turn this off?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The following lines should help:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <CopyRetryCount>0</CopyRetryCount>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You should add them into your project file (which is `*.*proj`, e.g., `csproj`), right after the opening `<Project>` tag.

To solve the problem globally, these lines should be placed in `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets` right after the opening `<Project>` tag.
More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx

Not sure if it can cause some build problems in future - I found this out right now.

**Update:**
For VS 2013 old location does not work anymore, so you can place these lines in `c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Microsoft.Common.props`.

Comment: Thank you sir. This will save me hours over my lifetime. I am sure that this idea sounds good in theory but it's a tremendous annoyance in practice.

Comment: VS should have an option for that at the UI.

Comment: any ideas how it can be applied for a whole solution ?

Comment: @isxaker not per-solution, but you can define it for a whole directory tree with a [`Directory.Build.props` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-by-directory?view=vs-2022#directorybuildprops-example).