# Change Visual Studio 2012 build copy retry count

Tags: c#, compilation, visual-studio-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [vs11: how to stop msbuild copy tasks retrying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354114/vs11-how-to-stop-msbuild-copy-tasks-retrying)

I sometimes work on a legacy C# project that takes over a minute to build even when able to multithread to 4 cores.  As such, it is not uncommon for me to loose focus while I wait.

Sometimes this build will take extra long (and ultimately fail) if I forget to close any portion of the applications being build.  Visual Studio gives an error of the form

> Error #   Could not copy "{File}" to "{DestinationFile}". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed. {Assembly}

In VS2008 and VS2010, I would get such errors but there was no retry count so the build failed faster.  I would like to set the count to 0 to restore the behavior from previous versions.  Could some please tell me where the setting is because I cannot find it?

Comment: It seems to me you are not focusing on the root cause of your failures -- the locked resources. Have you considered creating a pre-build script that will close open files, or at least alert you that certain resources have open locks? Also, you might have a look at .Net Demon (http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/dotnet-demon/) to help you with your long build times.

Comment: @ScottRFrost Not a duplicate, linked question addresses the locking issue, I just want to change the retry count.

Comment: @Heather, yes, there may be other solutions but I think it is valid to want to change the count.  In other situations I may want to set it to 2 because I have found some retries are helpful but 10 being overkill.

Comment: I think that http://stackoverflow.com/a/12479564/331820 may help you. I have same question but this is only solution I've found.

Comment: @MeFCorvi Thanks for finding the solution :)